# TMS tile layer in ESRI ArcGIS iOS API

Tags: arcgis-ios, arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios

I asked this particular question [on the official iPhone SDK forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/9283-Subclass-an-AGSTiledMapServiceLayer-to-access-a-TMS-layer) as well.

I have seen a working example of a `TiledMapServiceLayer` subclass that overrides the `GetTileUrl(int level, int row, int col)` method to point to a TMS-compliant service. This is in the .NET API. I tried implementing

```
-(NSString *)tileURL:(NSInteger)level row:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column
```

and various variations but to no avail.

Is there a workaround for this or does the ArcGIS iOS SDK just not support TMS?

Answer (score 0):

According to ESRI the iOS SDK supports Tiled Map Services

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/iphone/reference/interface_a_g_s_tiled_map_service_layer.html

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from AGSTiledServiceLayer and implement this function:

-(NSURL*)urlForTileKey:(AGSTileKey *)key

That's all you need to do.